# My C++ function gives unusual error, regarding declaration

Tags: c++, disjoint-sets, disjoint-union

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void union(int x, int y, int link[], int size[])
{
    int a = find(x, link); int b = find(y, link);
    if (size[a] < size[b])
        swap(a,b);
    if ( a != b)
    {
        size[a] += size[b];
        link[b] = link[a];
    }
}


int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I just can't figure out what the hell I am doing wrong. I checked multiple times but to no avail. It's probably something very stupid. It keeps giving the following errors.

```
file.cpp:19:11: error: expected identifier before '(' token
void union(int x, int y, int link[], int size[])
        ^
file.cpp:19:12: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
void union(int x, int y, int link[], int size[])
            ^~~
file.cpp:19:12: error: expected ')'
before 'int'
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` is a fairly toxic combination, because (a) it is non-portable, and (b) it pulls the entire C++ runtime library into the global namespace, risking further collisions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`union` is a reserved keyword in C++, and so, you cant use it for a function name. Rename it to something else, for example `union_`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks man.. I am a newbie and wasn't using an IDE so couldn't figure out that on my own..

Comment: @AnantAgarwal No problem